# jquery image gallery stacking order problem

Tags: jquery, animation

Ok.The image gallery has thumbnails on the right side. They're slanted as perspective, and there's a space between them. When you click or hover on the thumbnail, it translates to the left and disappears quickly to give the impression that when the real picture shows up, its the same one but scaled and with no angle.

I'm trying to find a way to have the thumbnail that's hidden behind the big picture, return back under the pile. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en">
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="plug.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="plug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
     <img id="thumb"src="pics/tu1.png" width="355" height="335"alt="">
     <img id="thumb2"src="pics/tu2.png" width="355" height="335"alt="">
     <img id="thumb3"src="pics/tu3.png" width="355" height="335"alt="">
     <img id="thumb4"src="pics/tu4.png" width="355" height="335"alt="">
     <img id="pic"src="pics/slider3.jpg" width="510" height="768" alt="">
     <img id="pic2"src="pics/slider2.jpg" width="510" height="768" alt="">
     <img id="pic3"src="pics/slider1.jpg" width="510" height="768" alt="">
     <img id="pic4"src="pics/home.jpg" width="510" height="768" alt="">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
img#pic {
  position:absolute;
  display: none;
}

img#pic2 {
  position:absolute;
  display: none;
}

img#pic3 {
  position:absolute;
  display: none;
}

img#pic4 {
  position:absolute;
  display: none;
}

img#thumb {
  position:absolute;
  top:410px;
  left:470px;
  z-index:20;
}

img#thumb2 {
  position:absolute;
  top:410px;
  left:525px;
  z-index: 19;
}

img#thumb3 {
   position:absolute;
   top:400px;
   left:580px;
   z-index: 18;
}

img#thumb4 {
   position:absolute;
   top:400px;
   left:635px;
   z-index: 17;
}

#content { 
   position:relative;
   width:1000px;
   height:768px;
   top:200px;
   left:100px;
   border:2px solid black;
   text-align: left;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#thumb').click(function() {
    $('#thumb').animate({
        left:'-=350'
    },250,"linear",function() {
        $('#thumb').hide();
        $('#pic').show();
    });
});


$('#thumb2').click(function() {
    $('#thumb2').animate({
        left:'-=350'
    },250,"linear",function(){
        $('#thumb2').hide();
        $('#pic2').show();
    });
});

$('#thumb3').click(function() {
    $('#thumb3').animate({
        left:'-=350'
    },250,"linear",function(){
        $('#thumb3').hide();
        $('#pic3').show();
    });
});

$('#thumb4').click(function() {
    $('#thumb4').animate({
        left:'-=350'
    },250,"linear",function(){
        $('#thumb4').hide();
        $('#pic4').show();
    });
});

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better base to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/marijnvdwerf/Cn8qe/1/
For maintainability I've made some changes in you html/css/javascript; I've added a container for thumbs, and full-sized pics, and added an event to each item in `#thumbs`. The function checks the index of the clicked item, and shows the item in `#pics` with the same index. I'd recommend setting the overlap of the thumbs in `#thumbs img`, so it's the same for every image (also way easier if you decide you need 10 pics instead of 4).